# Prove that this is a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

${(x^2+(y-2)^2-1)(x^2+(y+2)^2-1)(x^2+y^2-16)}=-z^2$

[image]

By definition, "smooth manifold" means having a atlas of $C^\infty$.

But how can I compose a atlas of $C^\infty$?

I'm stuck at the outset.

It seems to me that the manifold is like a double torus (=2 dimension), therefore I think I have to make charts to $\mathbb R^2$

Then...I don't know. Please help me.

Comment: Did you attempt to find the critical points of this function (zeroes of the gradient)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving a manifold by specifing and atlas is just one way of proceeding. Another one is to use the following important theorem:

> if $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, $f: M \to N$ is a smooth map and $n \in f(M)$ is a [regular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)) for $f$, then $f^{-1} (\{n\})$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ of dimension $\dim M - \dim N$.

In your case, let $f : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ be given by

$$f(x,y,z) = [x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + z^2 .$$

To show that $0 \in f(M)$ just notice that $f(2\sqrt 2, 2\sqrt 2, 0) = 0$ (because the third factor in that product of brackets is $0$).

Let $p \in f^{-1} (\{0\})$. Showing that $f$ is a submersion at $p$ amounts to showing that $\Bbb d _p f \ne 0$, i.e. that all the partial derivatives at $p$ are non-zero. But

$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} = 2x [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + [x^2+(y-2)^2-1] 2x (x^2+y^2-16) + \\
[x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] 2x \ ,\\
\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} = 2(y-2) [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + [x^2+(y-2)^2-1] 2(y+2) (x^2+y^2-16) + \\
[x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] 2y \ ,\\
\frac {\partial f} {\partial z} = 2z .$$

Assuming that $\Bbb d _p f = 0$ we get the system (I have simplified all the equations by $2$)

$$\begin{cases}
x \{ [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + [x^2+(y-2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + \\
[x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] \} = 0 \ ,\\
(y-2) [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) + [x^2+(y-2)^2-1] (y+2) (x^2+y^2-16) + \\
[x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] y = 0 \ ,\\
z = 0 \ .
\end{cases}$$

The third equation is easy and, if $p = (x,y,z)$, gives us $z=0$, and we shall drop this equation from the following analysis. Since $p$ must also satisfy the equation $f(p) = 0$, and since $z=0$, it follows that $(x,y)$ must satisfy the equation $[x^2+(y-2)^2-1] [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) = 0$. Since there are three factors, there will be three corresponding cases.

1. $x^2+(y-2)^2-1 = 0$.

   In this case the system simplifies to

   $$\begin{cases}
   x [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) = 0 \ ,\\
   (y-2) [x^2+(y+2)^2-1] (x^2+y^2-16) = 0 \ .\\
   \end{cases}$$

   Again, there are three cases, given by the three factors in the first equation.

   1.1. $x=0$: combining it with $x^2+(y-2)^2-1 = 0$ you get $(y-2)^2 = 1$ (having $3$ and $1$ for solutions), and the second equation becomes

   $$(y-2) [(y+2)^2-1] (y^2-16) = 0 ,$$

   which is not verified by either $3$ or $1$. Therefore, this case is impossible.

   1.2. $x^2+(y+2)^2-1 = 0$: combining it with $x^2+(y-2)^2-1 = 0$ you get $(y+2)^2 = (y-2)^2$ (having for solution $y=0$), whence $x^2 + 1 = 0$, which does not have real roots. Therefore, this case is impossible.

   1.3. $x^2+y^2-16 = 0$: combining it with $x^2+(y-2)^2-1 = 0$ you get $19 -4y = 0$, so $y = \frac {19} {4}$, whence $x^2 = 16 - \left( \frac {19} {4} \right)^2 < 0$, which does not have real roots. Therefore, this case is impossible.

By now you should have understood how to treat the remaining two cases: $x^2+(y+2)^2-1 = 0$ and $x^2+y^2-16 = 0$, and their corresponding subcases. I won't do them for you because they are elementary: in all of these cases the equations won't have real solutions. We conclude that all the points of $f^{-1} (\{0\})$ are regular points, therefore $f^{-1} (\{0\})$ is indeed a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$ (therefore a manifold) of dimension $3-1 = 2$.